# Import Oracle dump from Amazon RDS

Tags: linux, oracle, perl

I have successfully transferred my dump files to my RDS database instance based on  http://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/strategies-for-migrating-oracle-database-to-aws.pdf

Now, I want to reverse this process: transfer files from RDS to linux server, from dump_file_dir to my local linux machine. I am aware there are only a few lines I need to change, but I couldn't get it to work. Any tips is appreciated.

Original Perl script:

```
use DBI;
use warnings;
use strict;

# RDS instance info
my $RDS_PORT=1521;
my $RDS_HOST="<my rds instance>";
my $RDS_LOGIN="<myuser>/*******";
my $RDS_SID="<ORCL_LIKE>"; 

#The $ARGV[0] is a parameter you pass into the script
my $dirname = "DATA_PUMP_DIR";
my $fname = $ARGV[0];

my $data = "dummy";
my $chunk = 8192;

my $sql_open = "BEGIN perl_global.fh := utl_file.fopen(:dirname, :fname, 'wb', :chunk); END;";
my $sql_write = "BEGIN utl_file.put_raw(perl_global.fh, :data, true); END;";
my $sql_close = "BEGIN utl_file.fclose(perl_global.fh); END;";
my $sql_global = "create or replace package perl_global as fhutl_file.file_type; end;";

my $conn = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:host='.$RDS_HOST.';sid='.$RDS_SID.';port='.$RDS_PORT,$RDS_LOGIN, '') || die ( $DBI::errstr . "\n");

my $updated=$conn->do($sql_global);
my $stmt = $conn->prepare ($sql_open);
$stmt->bind_param_inout(":dirname", \$dirname, 12);
$stmt->bind_param_inout(":fname", \$fname, 12);
$stmt->bind_param_inout(":chunk", \$chunk, 4);
$stmt->execute() || die ( $DBI::errstr . "\n");

open (INF, $fname) || die "\nCan't open $fname for reading: $!\n";
binmode(INF);
$stmt = $conn->prepare ($sql_write);
my %attrib = ('ora_type','24');
my $val=1;
while ($val> 0) {
  $val = read (INF, $data, $chunk);
  $stmt->bind_param(":data", $data , \%attrib);
  $stmt->execute() || die ( $DBI::errstr . "\n") ; };
die "Problem copying: $!\n" if $!;
close INF || die "Can't close $fname: $!\n";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare ($sql_close);
  $stmt->execute() || die ( $DBI::errstr . "\n") ;
```

Comment: This script works fine with uploading from linux to RDS, but I want to download from RDS to linux by modifying the script.

Comment: This script runs on your remote RDS host or local linux? If local, have you tried "scp" to copy the file from remote to local?

Comment: Exactly what files (or kinds of files) are you trying to transfer from that directory?  The previous transfers (local -> RDS) cannot have been datafiles, RDS uses OMF structure only.

Answer (score 0):

Below is modification of above script to download the file, I needed to download the file to disk. However amazon provide a function to download the file to s3 can also be used.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# The script can be used to copy files out of RDS DUMP DIR
#
# Usage : perl <this_script.pl> <DB_FILE_TO_EXP.dmp> <DB_NAME> <Password>
#   User defaults to appmaster
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dump_file = $ARGV[0];
my $databasename = $ARGV[1];
my $databasepass = $ARGV[2];
my $datestring = locattime();

get_files_from_db($dump_file, $datestring, $databasepass);

## Logger
sub logger {
    $datestring = localtime();
    print "$datestring : @_\n"
}

## Function to get file
sub get_files_from_db {
    logger("Working on file $_[0]");
    use DBI;
    my $dirname = "DATA_PUMP_DIR";
    my $fname = $_[0];
    my $data = "dummy";
    my $chunk = 32767;
    my $sql_open = "BEGIN perl_global.fh := utl_file.fopen(:dirname, :fname, 'rb', :chunk); END;";
    my $sql_read = "BEGIN utl_file.get_raw(perl_global.fh, :data, NULL); END;";
    my $sql_close = "BEGIN utl_file.fclose(perl_global.fh);";
    my $sql_global = "create or replace package perl_global as fh utl_file.file_type; END;";

    ## Defaulting to appmaster
    my $conn = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:',"appmaster\@$_[1]", $_[2]) || die ($DBI:errstr, "appmaster\@$_[1],$_[2]\n"));

    my $updated = $conn->do($sql_global);
    my $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_open);
    $stmt->bind_param_inout(":dirname", \$dirname, 12);
    $stmt->bind_param_inout(":fname", \$fname, 12);
    $stmt->bind_param_inout(":chunk", \$chunk, 4);
    $stmt->execute()|| die( $DBI::errstr , "Failed to execute\n");

    open(INF, ">", $fname)|| die "can't open $fname for reading $!\n";
    binmode(INF);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare ($sql_read);
    my %attrib = ('ora_type' '24');
    my $val_read = 1;
    while ($val_read > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_param(":data", $data, $chunk, \%attrib);
        $stmt->execute() || die ( $DBI:errstr, "Failed to execute\n");
        $val_read = $val_read + 32767;
        print INF $data;
    };
    close INF || die "can't close $fname $!\n";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_close);
    $stmt->execute()|| die( $DBI::errstr , "Failed to execute close\n");
    $datestring = localtime();
    logger("Competed for file $_[0]");
}
__END__
```